# Serve top level domain as static html page in next.js?

Tags: html, redirect, next.js

In next.js you can use the "public" directory in your root directory to serve static assets. I have my index.html file in this directory because I want my landing page to be purely static.

However, when using `next` or `next start`, I cannot access my landing page at http://localhost:3000/. I can only access my landing page at "http://localhost:3000/index.html".

Is there a way to setup next.js, so the top level domain (http://localhost:3000) will serve my landing page?

Comment: You *can* have a default `index.js`

Comment: I know i can have a default `index.js`. But my landing page is a simple html file, not a react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js router serves only pages exported from `.js`, `.ts` and `.tsx` in `pages` directory.

You would need a custom server that would serve anything outside of that.

[Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

Also, if you use a reverse proxy like `nginx` you could handle this request by the server before it hits Node.js.

What is the use case of it? If the landing page is just a `.html` file, you can wrap it in a Next.js page. With server side rendering, the page will be pre-rendered on the server and served the same as it was just a `.html` file.

Alternatively, if you can't convert HTML to JSX you could use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set raw HTML code to React's `render()`.
However, beware of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Wrapping it requires a decent chunk of work, since it's a large HTML file, with script tags in the header, etc.

Comment: @Roymunson, I've updated the answer with another option using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. If you can't convert HTML to a React component, resolve it with a custom server / reverse proxy, this is a viable option.

Answer (score 5):

You can add rewrites to your `next.config.js`. To allow the url `mysite.com/` to point to `/public/index.html`, I added this to my config (with the content in my `/public` directory):

```
rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/index.html",
      }
    ]
}
```

Note: `index.jsx/.tsx` will take precedence over files in `/public`

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Comment: this is a good solution, unfortunately it doesn't work when using `next export`. You'd think there would be a way to serve static html files when exporting a static site...